# Sort a list containing classes based on class private members

Tags: c++, list, debugging, stl

I have a list which contains a class

```
list<PointTwoD> point
```

This is my declaration of my class

```
class PointTwoD:public locationdata
{
public:
  PointTwoD();
  PointTwoD(string,int,int,float,float,int,int);

  void set_x(int);
  int get_x();

  void set_y(int);
  int get_y();

  void set_civIndex(float);
  float get_civIndex();

  friend class MissionPlan;

private:
  int x;
  int y;
  float civIndex;

};
```

I am trying to sort the list based on the private member civIndex. I have tried calling the sort function on the list but it does not work .
Can someone advise me how do i sort the list based on the value of private member civIndex ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a less-than operator to your class:

```
  bool operator<(const PointTwoD& other) const
  {
      return civIndex < other.civIndex;
  }
```

If you don't want a generic less-than operator but still need to sort the list, you can provide a comparison function that does the same thing:

```
bool compare_PointTwoD(const PointTwoD& first, const PointTwoD& second)
{
    return first.get_civIndex() < second.get_civIndex();
}
```

And invoke the sort like this:

```
std::list<PointTwoD> lpt;
lpt.sort(compare_PointTwoD);
```

Comment: How do i use the less-than operator??

Comment: @Computernerd: You don't need to use it yourself, once you add it to your class the `list::sort()` function will "just work".

Comment: How do i sort from biggest to smallest instead of smallest to biggest?? I tried changing the operator : < to > but it does not work

Comment: Just change what the operator does internally (`return civIndex > other.civIndex;`).